# angularjs design pattern and best practice to get data from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, factory-pattern

what im trying to achive is have an Model function that contain all the object behaviour, and a factory singleton that creates, save, update, and keep collections of such models, so that i can use them inside angular controllers.

First question: **does angular provide a way to create Models to be injected in services so that i dont have to save them in window.interfaces* ?**

using such approach i can contain behaviour of my objects in their own models,yet **performance wise, how bad is this approach ?** does angular watchers will easily track this or it will trigger un-needed digest cycles ?

Fiddle for example
http://jsfiddle.net/zalabany/j230cuy4/1/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('People', function() {
  var container = [];
  var self = this;

  this.all = function() {
    console.log('called all', container);
    return container;
  }

  this.createMany = function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(el) {
      container.push(new window.interfaces.Person(el));
    });
    return container;
  }

  this.createOne = function(obj) {
    var index = container.push(new window.interfaces.Person(obj));
    console.log('add one to container', index, container);
    return container[index - 1];
  }

});


function ctrl2(People, $scope) {
  $scope.people = People.all();
};

function ctrl1(People, $scope) {
  $scope.people = People.all();
  $scope.add = function() {
    console.log(People.createOne({
      id: 1,
      fullname: 'Jhon Doe'
    }));
  }
};

window.interfaces = window.interfaces || {};
window.interfaces.Person = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  data = data || {};

  //TypeCasting For properties
  this.id = parseInt(data.id);
  this.saved = !!(this.id);
  this.deleted = !!(data.time_deleted > 0);
  this.fullname = String(data.fullname + '');
  data = undefined; //clear data variable. we dont need it anymore

  ///Methods
  this.first_name = function() {
    return self.fullname.substring(0, self.fullname.indexOf(' '));
  };
  this.last_name = function() {
    return self.fullname.substring(self.fullname.lastIndexOf(' '));
  }
  this.change = function(v) {
    self.fullname = (self.fullname === 'hello world') ? 'Was hello' : v;
  }
}
```

```css
div[ng-controller] {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="ctrl1">
  <h2>
  Ctrl1
  </h2>
  <label ng-repeat="person in people">{{person.first_name()}}</label>
  <button ng-click="add();">Click Me to create objects</button>
</div>
<div ng-controller="ctrl2">
  <h2>
  Ctrl2
  </h2>
  <label ng-repeat="person in people">
    {{person.first_name()}}
    <button ng-click="person.change('new name');">Change</button>
  </label>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly** putting stuff inside window is a security hazard. Anyone can manipulate them.

**Secondly** Factories and Services are *models* that you inject into controllers.

> I think what you are looking for is are **providers**

Do read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) and [this](http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/).

Hope I could help.

Comment: so in given example, what is the correct provider for People and person classes ? is it correct implementation to have people as an angular service and person as angular constant ?

Comment: I'm kinda confused, if you could just explain your aim with the people and person thing.. I mean why do you need them both? Generally we would have a Person service or a Person Factory from which we would call apis through functions like Person.all or Person.one and so on...

Comment: person will have methods like getting name of user after doing some logic, validating user is ready to be saved in database, etc. 
People is for collections of persons, it has logic of how to retrieve them from database, how to create them,

Comment: @Zalaboza so you want the Person interface to be used for the currently logged in user and the People factory to call your apis? If that's the case, you should use a service like Auth which will expose methods like Auth.name and Auth.isAGoodPerson and things like that.. make sense?